# Load routes from different modules into a named router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I have some modules that I use for different sections of a cargo tracking system. Some of them are: `scheduleModule`, `equipmentsModule`, `driverModule` etc.
Each of these modules have its own routes that are lazy loaded, and each one have its own different paths relative to the root.

```
  {
    path: 'equipamentos',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/equipments/equipments.module').then(m => m.EquipmentsModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'schedules',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/schedules/schedules.module').then(m => m.SchedulesModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'drivers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/drivers/drivers.module').then(m => m.DriversModule)
  },
```

and each of the modules has its own child routes for the entity details and actions like editing and listing.

I'm opening the main listing pages on a main `router-outlet` and the navigation of every item details are also opened inside the main outlet. Now I'm changing it to be opened on a different named `router-outlet` for things like details page inside a drawer like sidebar.

For things directly related to the module that is rendered in the main `router-outlet`, but there are some things that are out of the main scope but have access points from within the details page of the main entity.

Now with the sub outlet I have something like this:

```
<div class='mainPage'>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<sidebar-drawer>
   <router-outlet name="drawer"></router-outlet>
</sidebar-drawer>
```

As an example, I have a schedule list on a route `/schedule/list` and then for me to view the details of it from the list, I have a button that takes me to the `/schedule/details/:id`.

On those routes I did move the rendering of the details page to the drawer outlet with something like:

```
   this.router.navigate(['schedules', {outlets: {drawer: ['details', schedule.id]}}], {relativeTo: this.route.root});
```

And also from within the details drawer outlet I can navigate to `/schedule/edit/:id` without closing it, and without losing the list page behind the drawer.

The problem now is that I need to navigate the user also inside the drawer to a diffrent module page like `/drive/details/:id`.

```
 this.router.navigate([{outlets: {drawer: ['/', 'driver', 'details', selectedDriverId]}}], {relativeTo: this.route.root});
```

As it doesn't share the same base path with the schedules module I got an error of a not found route.

How would I allow the user to navigate to a different module's route keeping the main router rendered page as is. Something like an independant navigation on the main and the secondary named `router-outlet`.

PS. Both the main and the named `router-outlets` are in the main `app.component.html` outside the child modules, inside the main `app.module.ts`.

PS2. I'm using Angular v12.

PS3. I actually created a github repo with a sample of how it should work, but it also didn't

https://github.com/BarretoDiego/router-test